# Configuring MS Edge to open web page in IE mode version 8

Tags: windows-10, group-policy, microsoft-edge, microsoft-edge-devtools

I know you can set Edge to open up a designated page in IEmode.  You can do it either through the edge browser where the site will stay for a maximum number of days, or you can do it through Enterprise Policies or some such thing that the IT department looks after and is way beyond me.

We have an external 3rd party web page we need to use periodically that the IT department has graciously added to the policy list to open in IEmode.  Great!  The problem is that it opens up in IEmode version 11 where it does not work.  We need it to open up in IEmode version 8 where it does work.

When we have the page open we can run the following command:

```
%systemroot%\system32\f12\IEChooser.exe
```

We can then set it in two locations to use version 8, the page reloads and everything works.  However, due to the periodic nature of needing this website,  the command is often forgotten, hard to remember the details of, and need several different user to remember what to click on each time.

Is there a way through the enterprise policy thing to force the version of IEmode to be used and not just the default?

I am trying to educate myself a bit before I make any request of the IT department.

So far I have just been bumbling my way through a batch file but it only goes so far.

```
@echo off
Title Batch IEmode chooser
start C:\"Program Files (x86)"\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe HTTPS://HiCo.MTO.AD.GOV.ON.CA
timeout /t 5
%systemroot%\system32\f12\IEChooser.exe
```